# Unzipping a .zip file in Python 2.4.2 (Linux)

Tags: python, linux, extract, zip

I have to use `python 2.4.2` to unzip a `.zip` file. However, the included `.zip` file in `python 2.4.2` does not have either `extractall()` or `extract()` attributes. Could someone please tell me how to extract a `.zip` file with the following structure:

fileABC.zip

```
- FolderA
    -A.txt
- FolderB
    -B.txt
```

I just need to extract fileABC.zip to the current directory.

EDIT:

I saw the answer to this question:
[How to unzip a file with Python 2.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7806563/how-to-unzip-a-file-with-python-2-4)

However, python 2.4.2 does not seem to have the extract() attribute.

Comment: You can still use `read()` and manually write the content to a file.

Comment: I found another zipfile 2.4 question with great answers so marked as dup.

Comment: But that question uses zfile.extract(), which does not exist in 2.4.2. It probably exists in 2.4.4 (Though I'm not sure about that).